# login with nextjs and laravel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, next.js

The backend of my site is written with Laravel. When I try with postman, everything is correct and I see the entered user information, but with next js, after entering the site (Auth::attempt(...)), the result is true, but I can't see user information.
Even a cookie is set, but auth()->user() always returns null. And I also use sanctum Laravel package

component axios

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://api.lanext.test',
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  },
  withCredentials: true
});
```

component useAuth

```
import useSWR from "swr";
import axios from '@/lib/axios'
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function useAuth({} = {}) {

    const router = useRouter()

    const { data: user, error, mutate } = useSWR('/api/v1/admin',
        () => axios.get('/api/v1/admin').then(response => console.log(response.data.data, "ok"))
    )

    const csrf = () => axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')

    const login = async ({ setErrors, ...props }) => {

        axios.post('/api/v1/login', props)
            .then(
                () => mutate && router.push('/')
            )
            .catch(
                error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    // if (error?.response?.status !== 422) throw error
                    // setErrors(Object.values(error.response.data.errors).flat())
                }
            )
    }

    return {
        user,
        csrf,
        login
    }
}
```

component login

```
    const [submitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false);

    const {login} = useAuth();

    const handleSubmit = async (values, actions) => {
        setSubmitting(true);
        await login(values)
        setSubmitting(false);
    };
```

user component = It always returns null

```
const { user } = useAuth();
```